# Вычисление суммы n членов последовательности

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class Ideone {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int n = Integer.parseInt(r.readLine());
        ff g = new ff();
        System.out.println(g.sum(3));
    }
}

class ff {
    double sum(int b) {
        double sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < b; i++)
            sum += (i + 1) / (i + 2);
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Дано натуральное число `n`, надо вычислить сумму `n` членов последовательности `1/2 + 3/4 + 5/6 + 7/8 + ...`.

Почему считается неправильно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы деление не было целочисленным, можно, например, в начало выражения добавлять `1.0 *`.

Также либо при суммировании должно участвовать `2 * i`:

```
sum += 1.0 * (2 * i + 1) / (2 * i + 2);
```

Либо `i` должно идти до `2 * n` с шагом `2`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2 * n; i += 2)
{
    sum += 1.0 * (i + 1) / (i + 2);
}
```

Пример целиком:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 * n; i += 2)
    {
        sum += 1.0 * (i + 1) / (i + 2);
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

А с использованием Java 8 и преобразованием формулы это может выглядеть так:

```
double sum = IntStream.range(1, n + 1).mapToDouble(i -> 1 - 0.5 / i).sum();
```